# How to run a method asynchronously inside a loop

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous

How to run *bar()* asynchronously in the case bellow?
I want to run *foo()* and *bar()* in a loop. But I don't want to wait for full execution of *bar()* and proceed to next iterations.
Printing results show that it works step-by-step instead of asynchronously.

```
import time
import concurrent
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

def func_foo_bar(j,executor):
    foo(j)
    bar(j,executor)

def foo(j):
    [print(f"FOO calling {j}{i}") for i in range(3)]

def bar(j, executor):
    future_slow = {executor.submit(slow_func, j,x): x for x in range(3)}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_slow):
        if not future.exception():
            r = future.result()
            # print(r)

def slow_func(j,i):
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f"BAR calling {j}{i}")

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
[func_foo_bar(x, executor) for x in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake =)
I just need to move out as_completed method out of the loop:

```
import time
import concurrent
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

def func_foo_bar(j,executor):
    foo(j)
    future_slow=bar(j,executor)
    return future_slow

def foo(j):
    # time.sleep(2)
    [print(f"FOO calling {j}{i}") for i in range(3)]

def bar(j, executor):
    future_slow = [executor.submit(slow_func, j,x) for x in range(3)]
    return future_slow


def slow_func(j,i):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f"BAR calling {j}{i}")

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
future_slow_list=[func_foo_bar(x, executor) for x in range(5)]
for future_slow in future_slow_list:
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_slow):
        if not future.exception():
            r = future.result()
            # print(r)
```